# Move value along a sequence

Tags: r, sequence

I am aiming to produce a sequence something like this:

```
> c(1, rep(9, 7))
[1] 1 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
> c(9, 1, rep(9, 6))
[1] 9 1 9 9 9 9 9 9
> c(rep(9, 2), 1, rep(9, 5))
[1] 9 9 1 9 9 9 9 9
```

In essence, I have a sequence that stays constant, but I want to move a value along, one space at a time.

Obviously I could write this out in a way similar to what I have done, but my real sequence is much larger so this isn't that practical. My search for this has been somewhat futile so any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a matrix and replace the diagonal, i.e.

```
m1 <-matrix(data = 9, nrow = 8, ncol = 8)
diag(m1) <- 1
m1

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    1    9    9    9    9    9    9    9
#[2,]    9    1    9    9    9    9    9    9
#[3,]    9    9    1    9    9    9    9    9
#[4,]    9    9    9    1    9    9    9    9
#[5,]    9    9    9    9    1    9    9    9
#[6,]    9    9    9    9    9    1    9    9
#[7,]    9    9    9    9    9    9    1    9
#[8,]    9    9    9    9    9    9    9    1
```

A one liner for that would be:

```
`diag<-`(matrix(data = 9, nrow = 8, ncol = 8),1)
```

Comment: This seems to be the most elegant way of achieving the sequence overall, so thank you! I tried to make it into a oneliner (without resorting to `;`) but can't seem to find a way of including the diagonal call in the matrix, or the matrix in the diagonal call. But I can live with two lines compared to the length it was going to be doing it my way! Thanks

Comment: You can always turn it into a function

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. Thanks :)

Comment: A one-liner translation of this solution: `"diag<-"(matrix(data = 9, nrow = 8, ncol = 8),1)`

Comment: Anyone minds explaining the one liner? I don't get the "diag<-" part. Thanks.

Comment: @Haboryme it means that `diag<-` is passed as an argument between matrix(...) and 1

Comment: I replaced the quote with the backtick (which is hard to make in the comments, but it's more "proper" in this context). @Haboryme This is how replacement functions work in R. For instance, calling `names(x)<-y` actually is translated in calling the `"names<-"` function with `x` and `y` arguments and assigning the result back to `x`. So, `names(x)<-y` is just syntactic sugar for the real call which is `x<-"names<-"(x,y)`. You need quote or backticks around `"names<-"`, otherwise the parser won't get it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stats::filter`:

```
x <- c(1, rep(9, 7))

for (i in 1:8) print(x <- c(filter(x, c(0, 1), circular = TRUE, sides = 1)))
#[1] 9 1 9 9 9 9 9 9
#[1] 9 9 1 9 9 9 9 9
#[1] 9 9 9 1 9 9 9 9
#[1] 9 9 9 9 1 9 9 9
#[1] 9 9 9 9 9 1 9 9
#[1] 9 9 9 9 9 9 1 9
#[1] 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 1
#[1] 1 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

Obviously, this moves all values along and might not be what you are looking for if you have more than two different values in the sequence. Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: This is great except that the first element of the sequence ends up at the end!

Comment: I do not understand your comment.

Comment: The last row should be the first row

Comment: Are you complaining that I didn't print out the initial `x` and ran the loop to 8 instead if 7? That's just to illustrate how this solution works. You dind't state in your question that you want the exact matrix as given in Sotos' answer. My solution can be preferable if you don't need the whole matrix at once and memory consumption is an issue.

Comment: It's not a complaint... it's just that the first sequence should come first - that's all

Answer (score 1):

An option is `embed`

```
 embed(c(rev(v1),rev(v1)), length(v1))
 #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
 #[1,]    1    9    9    9    9    9    9    9
 #[2,]    9    1    9    9    9    9    9    9
 #[3,]    9    9    1    9    9    9    9    9
 #[4,]    9    9    9    1    9    9    9    9
 #[5,]    9    9    9    9    1    9    9    9
 #[6,]    9    9    9    9    9    1    9    9
 #[7,]    9    9    9    9    9    9    1    9
 #[8,]    9    9    9    9    9    9    9    1
 #[9,]    1    9    9    9    9    9    9    9


embed(c(rev(v2),rev(v2)), length(v2))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]    1    5    5    5    3    2    5    7
# [2,]    7    1    5    5    5    3    2    5
# [3,]    5    7    1    5    5    5    3    2
# [4,]    2    5    7    1    5    5    5    3
# [5,]    3    2    5    7    1    5    5    5
# [6,]    5    3    2    5    7    1    5    5
# [7,]    5    5    3    2    5    7    1    5
# [8,]    5    5    5    3    2    5    7    1
# [9,]    1    5    5    5    3    2    5    7
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)
v2 <- c(1, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 5, 7)
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing a method I would never have thought of! This is the way to go if replacing more than just 1 value in the sequence. But for the purposes of what I need it's a bit more complex

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to get the same result:

```
x <- c(1, rep(9, 7))
sapply(8:1, function(n)c(tail(x,-n),head(x,n)))

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    9    9    9    9    9    9    9
[2,]    9    1    9    9    9    9    9    9
[3,]    9    9    1    9    9    9    9    9
[4,]    9    9    9    1    9    9    9    9
[5,]    9    9    9    9    1    9    9    9
[6,]    9    9    9    9    9    1    9    9
[7,]    9    9    9    9    9    9    1    9
[8,]    9    9    9    9    9    9    9    1
```